# ASP .NET Core 2 API routes to GET method then POST method on first request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httprequest

I noticed that after I restart my ASP .NET API and send a POST request the API routes to the GET request method and then my POST request method. This only happens on the first POST request after I restart the API. Each POST request after this one routes directly to my POST method without processing the GET request method. Below is the class methods from my API.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{

    //public class variable 
    private readonly fujimiContext _context;
    //constructor for ValuesController class
    public ValuesController(fujimiContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }
    // GET api/values
    // [Authorize(Policy = "RequireReadRole")]
    [HttpGet("bins")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetValues()
    {
       var values = await _context.FcbinCnfg.ToListAsync();

        return Ok(values);
    }

    // POST api/values
   // [Authorize(Policy = "RequireEditRole")]
    [HttpPost("sitepost")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] FcbinCnfg [] fcbincnfg)
    {
        if (fcbincnfg == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fcbincnfg));
        }

        string WindUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        string AppName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var obj in fcbincnfg){

                _context.Update(fcbincnfg[i]);
                i++;
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return StatusCode(201);
        }

        return BadRequest("this does not work");
    }
```

Startup.cs file

```
namespace FcBin.API
 {
 public class Startup
  {
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        var connection = @"Server=XXXXX\XXXX;Database=XXXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        services.AddDbContext<fujimiContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
       {
           options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;       
       });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
}
```

Angular Route

```
import { Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { BinConfigComponent } from './BinConfig/BinConfig.component';
import { BinResolver } from './_resolver/bin.resolver';


export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'binconfig'
  , component: BinConfigComponent
  , resolve: {binconfig: BinResolver}, runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'binconfig', pathMatch: 'full',   runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'}
];
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not suffering from browser predictive url typing?  I.e. chrome will predict what url you are typing and automatically go fetch it before you finish typing it.

If you really want to test it, use a rest test client, then you can confirm it's not the browser doing it.

Comment: I'm using firefox currently as my browser so I'm not sure if that problem would still be possible. How would I use a rest test client?

Comment: https://install.advancedrestclient.com/#/features

This is my favorite rest test client at the moment, also available as a chrome extension.

When debugging an api, you should optimally use a rest test client, not a browser.

Comment: However it does complicate things if you have authentication complications.  I.e. I'm building a rest api right now that uses pass through ADFS authentication from a parent domain.  The Authentication cookie gets passed to the API so that the api is claims authenticated.  I can't test it in a rest client because I don't have that cookie.  I have to copy the cookie headers out after logging in and put them in the rest client, big pita.

Comment: I'll take a look thank you. My setup currently is an Angular 2 front end and a ASP .NET back end. I get the issue when I leave my Angular 2 app running and then restart the ASP .NET back end. It gets worse when I add windows authentication in. It always processes the GET route before the POST route. its really strange

Comment: Yeah, just test it in a rest client before you focus on it being the API/Code, you could be chasing a white rabbit.

Also get Fiddler 2, and look at the actual requests being made.  You can see if the browser is requesting the main Get method via Fiddler.

Don't assume that because you pressed enter on a url and it requested the get method that something is wrong, it might be the request, and nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Also, add your global.ascx Startup config code too, Routes.Config, WebApi.Config, etc etc, let us see all the route/register code and the code enabling attribute routing.

You could have a default route conflicting with your attribute routing.

Comment: So if I look at the API's terminal I see that the POST route matches to the GET method and then the POST method. See Below

Comment: Read my last comment, post the rest of the code I mentioned.

Comment: '''info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/api/values/sitepost application/json 1844
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      Policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Route matched with {action = "GetValues", controller = "Values"}. Executing action FcBin.API.Controllers.ValuesController.GetValues (FcBin.API)'''

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180465/discussion-between-hlatimer-and-ryan-mann).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue had nothing to do with my routes or the API. The issue was with my `save()` function in my Angular front end. I approached the function as a sequential problem when in actuality the browser/client approached my function from and efficiency stand point. Below is what I had that the browser would try to optimize

```
save() {
if (this.dirtyFlag) {
this.dbService.dbsave(this.binconfig).subscribe( () => {
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
}
if (this.isFoo && this.valid) {
  this.dbService.dbsavebin(this.newbin).subscribe( error => {
    console.log(error);
   });
} else if (!this.valid && this.isFoo) {
  this.toastr.warning('Enter a Bin Id');
}
 this.router.navigate(['/binconfig']);
}
```

Here I was having a route resolver reload the page which I triggered after a save. Tacking the route at the end of this save would result in the browser trying to optimize the POST / GET methods in the `save()` function and in the route resolver. I solved the issue by instead using the arrow function to execute the router navigation after a successful save.

```
save() {
if (this.dirtyFlag) {
this.dbService.dbsave(this.binconfig).subscribe( () => {
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
}, () => {
  this.router.navigate(['/binconfig']);
  this.toastr.success('Changes Saved');
  this.dirtyFlag = false;
});
}
if (this.isFoo && this.valid) {
  this.dbService.dbsavebin(this.newbin).subscribe( () => {
    this.router.navigate(['/binconfig']);
    this.toastr.success('New Bin Added');
    this.isFoo = false;
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
} else if (!this.valid && this.isFoo) {
  this.toastr.warning('Enter a Bin Id');
}

}
```